# radio validation is not working vee-validate (yup) Vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, validation

I'm using the vee-validate 4.5.0 and trying to add radio validation in Form, but It's not working.

Here is my sample ts code

`myradio: yup.string().oneOf(['value1', 'value2']).required()`

using the TypeScript for validating the radio

Here is my HTML code

```html
<Field v-slot="{ field, errorMessage }" name="myradio">
  <VField>
    <VControl>
      <input id="mints" v-model="events" type="checkbox" value="erc721:mint" />
    </VControl>
  </VField>
</Field>
```

Vue version - 3.2.12

codesandbox link-
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-christian-x0xkx?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue